# preg_replace all but numbers, letters, periods, and slash?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a regular expression that strips everything but letters. numbers, and periods.  How do I also add foreslashes to it?

```
$targetFile = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-.]/', '', $targetFileDirty);
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can escape the foreslash by putting a backslash before it - `$targetFile = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-.\/]/', '', $targetFileDirty);`

Alternatively, and perhaps better, you can use different delimiters instead, e.g. `$targetFile = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9-./]#', '', $targetFileDirty);`

Comment: Just a question, why do you need the "-" after the number 9 to indicate a period?

Comment: its indicating the - is allowed and a . on top of that

Answer (score 7):

To be unicode compatible you can use:

```
$targetFile = preg_replace('#[^\pL\pN./-]+#', '', $targetFileDirty);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply add an escaped slash: `[^A-Za-z0-9-.\\/]`

Comment: Eeek! I didn't look at my answer after I posted. Sorry, and thank you!