# PHP preg_replace (replace from string all characters except letters, numbers, and few characters)

Tags: php, preg-replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [preg_replace all but numbers, letters, periods, and slash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207069/preg-replace-all-but-numbers-letters-periods-and-slash)

I have a string and i want to replace from that string ALL CHARACTERS except:

- all alphabetical letters
- all numbers
- @
- ,
- .
- ;

Comment: Modify the linked answer to include the few other characters you need inside the `[]`

Comment: you want to replace with what? or you want to remove?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple [Preg_Replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with empty string:

```
preg_replace('/[^\w@,.;]/', '', $string);

[^] represents a list of characters NOT to match
\w Word character (abcABC0-9_)
,.; as the characters themselves
```

Comment: thank you very much for your \w and \d description, it was usefuly to me!!

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
preg_replace('/[^\pL\pN@,.;]+/', '', $string);
```

`\pL` is the unicode property for letters
`\pN` is the unicode property for numbers

Comment: *Finally* - someone answered the question! (not answered in dozens of other threads here on Stack) Up-voted.